# WinDBG under VMware Workstation Pro 16.2.3 zeros x87 FPUInstructionPointer when single-stepping

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode, fpu, x87

### Objective

I am learning exploit development and one of the topics is on writing shellcode.

Typically, msfvenom would do the job well with shikata ga nai encoding. The shellcode generated will also usually contains FPU instructions to obtain EIP to make it PIC.

The FPU instructions that I mentioned are:

```
dadc            fcmovu st, st(4)
d97424f4        fnstenv [esp-0Ch]
5d              pop ebp
```

### Environment

Microsoft Windows Version 1709 (Build 16299.2166) x86
Used WinDbg: 10.0.22621.755 X86 for debugging

### Expected outcome

When i was using the lab's VM, i was able to get the FPULastInstructionOpcode, where `esp` would point to the stack address containing the EIP value where `fcmovu` instruction was executed, hence the `pop ebp` would place the `eip` value to `ebp`.

### Received problem

Before i execute the `fcmovu` instruction, this is how my stack looked like:

```
01e0744c 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 83 0c 09 10 43 43 43 43  AAAAAAAA....CCCC
01e0745c 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 be 02 61 13 10 da  ............a...
01e0746c dc d9 74 24 f4 5d 29 c9 b1 52 83 c5 04 31 75 0e  ..t$.])..R...1u.
01e0747c 03 77 6f f1 e5 8b 87 77 05 73 58 18 8f 96 69 18  .wo....w.sX...i.
```

After I execute the `fnstenv` instruction:

```
01e0744c 41 41 41 41 7f 02 ff ff 41 00 ff ff fe ff ff ff  AAAA....A.......
01e0745c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff  ................
01e0746c dc d9 74 24 f4 5d 29 c9 b1 52 83 c5 04 31 75 0e  ..t$.])..R...1u.
01e0747c 03 77 6f f1 e5 8b 87 77 05 73 58 18 8f 96 69 18  .wo....w.sX...i.
```

my ESP is pointing at `0x1e0745c`, where the EIP value is expected to be in.
However, i received NULL value instead of the EIP value.

### Help

So what I would like to ask from the community here is why am I getting NULL value?
What am i doing wrongly?

I have read the x86 documentation and know that `fcmovu` is not the problem here.

This is exactly the same shellcode that i have used in the lab and i was able to receive the EIP value as expected.

I have also read from another post made in StackExchange [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154886/why-is-fnstenv-giving-me-a-null-address-in-my-shellcode-on-windows-xp) but the reply didn't feel like it answered the OP's question.

### Mitigated solution

With the help of Peter Cordes, I have found that WinDbg under VMWare Guest OS returns null values from `FPULastInstructionOpcode` when single stepping through x87 FPU instructions. This was an unexpected outcome and was mitigated by setting a breakpoint after the FPU instructions and running the shellcode. Not sure why the debugger in the VMWare clobbers the results like this, but some things just don't really need answers (or rather, probably too much work to investigate something that could be trivially mitigated).

Comment: When you single-step this code, is the x87 stack in use?  `fcmovu` won't fault if there are 5 values on the x87 stack so `st4` is valid.  The info should actually be in the saved FP environment from `fnstenv` - http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap3.htm#fstenv - the status word is saved at  `esp-0Ch + 4` where we can check if C1 was set to 0 by stack underflow (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcmovcc#fpu-flags-affected), and the tag word is there (http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm) to directly check.  But it would be easier for you to check yourself with a debugger.

Comment: I've checked the `fcmovCC/ fnstenv` behavior under Linux with all 8 combinations of: a) IE flag masked/unmasked; b) valid/invalid FPU stack; c) matching/non-matching test condition, and it always works. So, maybe there's some kind of emulation on the way in your case? If you could make a [mcve] and tell us the exact OS and debugging method that would be great. For example, you could start by making a simple assembly program with just those two instructions and check if it works with a debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for refining my post! sorry im not sure what you mean by whether x87 stack is used, but i am using x86 Windows 10 VM. i will edit my post to include this details.

Comment: If you don't know what the x87 stack is, go read http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm .  You're the one wanting to use this obfuscated technique of `fcmov` to cause an FP exception and then get EIP from `fnstenv`, instead of `jmp` forwards / `call` backwards (pushing a return address) / `pop ebp` like a normal person.  A debugger should be able to print the state of the x87 registers before (and after) `fcmov` as you single-step.

Comment: I just tried it on my Linux machine (not as an exploit, just a program running those 3 instructions, so the FPU freshly initialized).  i7-6700k (Skylake) on bare metal, no VM shenanigans.  The saved x87 control word (0x037f) was the same as yours except for the expected difference in precision-control (64-bit vs. MSVC setting it to 53-bit).  The status word was 0x0041, same as yours, so C1=0 (bit #9) as `fcmov` sets on stack underflow (which I know happened).  `pop EBP` did pop the address of the `fcmov` into EBP for me.  IDK why yours has zeros there; not a [mcve].

Comment: The fact that my x87 control word and status word were the same as yours (modulo the expected difference in the PC field) mean that difference in OS isn't a factor; the x87 FPU was in the same state.  (Also tag words match: `0xfffe`: all empty except the lowest reg, which contains a special value: NaN in this case from fcmov writing it.)  And the space you're popping was above ESP so can't be getting asynchronously clobbered.  Unless there's another thread that was writing this space as shared memory while your exploit was running, but that wouldn't happen consistently.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your prompt reply. I admit i am not super familiar with the intricacies of the assembly language/development side of things as i am merely following tutorials for writing shellcode exploits. `msfvenom` shellcode creates this technique to get reference to current EIP space, but my environment was not able to replicate the same results as the one in the Lab's VM. 

Also, I was able to get `fpsw==0x41` and `fptw==0xfffe`, just as you have mentioned, but the result is still null.

Comment: How *exactly* are you running this code?  What CPU model?  Is it in an emulator or something, like QEMU, or macOS Rosetta?  Is it inside any kind of VM?  Are you only single-stepping under a debugger?  Perhaps a debugger could be corrupting something, so maybe try just setting a breakpoint on or after the pop instruction, after `fcmov` + `fnstenv`.  I don't know of any hardware feature that would mask the last-fault address to `0x00000000` for security or other reasons, (and it wouldn't make sense for security hardening because call/pop has to work anyway).

Comment: @PeterCordes and you are right. i dont think there is another thread that is writing to this stack space. so if the problem is not on the FPU instruction set, i am more curious at what could be the possible reasons that is causing this unexpected result...

Comment: @PeterCordes This code is a result of an input stack overflow, in which the program will will return to a shared library address that contains `jmp esp`, where `esp` will point to the start of the NOP sled.

This code is running inside a VM with the Windows OS version, as edited in my post:  Windows Version 1709 (Build 16299.2166) x86, my host OS is running on AMD Ryzen 8 Pro 5860U.

When i just run my exploit, the program runs into an exception. when i single step it, i receive that error. but let me try your suggestion and place a breakpoint and run instead of single-stepping it

Comment: Inside what VM?  If setting a breakpoint after `fcmov` / `fnstenv` fixes it, you've probably found a bug in either the debugger, Windows, or the VM, clearing the `FPUInstructionPointer` in the x87 state when taking single-step debug interrupts.  GDB on Linux doesn't have this problem: I single-stepped each instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hello, it seems you are correct to suggest that the debugger could be corrupting something. After setting a breakpoint after the pop instruction, my `ebp` value contains the `eip` value where the `fcmovu` insn is executed. im still a little bewildered why this is the case, but thank you very much for your help! By the way, my Guest OS is running in VMware Workstation Pro 16.2.3 build-19376536

Comment: Ok, there you go, that's a key detail that needs to go in the question, and retitle to "WinDBG under <some VM> zeros x87 FPUInstructionPointer when single-stepping?" or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a bug in your VM or your debugger.**  If you can figure out which, report it to them.  Single-stepping should have the same result as letting the instructions run until you hit a breakpoint (which you confirm is working; thanks for testing that.)

This works correctly in GDB on Linux (on my i7-6700k CPU directly, no VM).  Even single-stepping `fcmov` then [`fnstenv`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fstenv:fnstenv), it stores the address of the `fcmov` as the `FPUInstructionPointer` in the FP environment, not `0x00000000`.  (That's what `pop ebp` loads.)

The bytes written to the stack on my system match yours for FPU control word<sup>1</sup>, status word, and tag word, so your FPU was in the same state.  That shouldn't matter anyway; setting `FPUInstructionPointer` to point at the last non-control FP instruction executed always happens, not just on FPU exceptions, according to vol.1 of Intel's x86 manuals ([section 8.1.8 x87 FPU Instruction and Data (Operand) Pointers](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf#page=201)).

I don't think there's any reason your AMD CPU would clear the x87 `FPUInstructionPointer` field while taking a single-step debug exception, so it's very likely a software bug, not a hardware difference between your AMD and my Intel.  The fact that it works when not stopping between `fcmov` and `fnstenv` confirms that AMD hardware does set this field the way Intel documents.  I guess it's *possible* (but unlikely) that AMD's `frstor` or `xrstor` doesn't properly restore that field, so make sure you include HW details when reporting this to the VM or debugger developers.

---

**Footnote 1**: Actually there's one difference: yours has control word = `0x027f` (precision control = 0b10 = 53-bit mantissa [like 32-bit MSVC sets](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/)), vs. mine having `0x037f` (precision control = 0b11 = 64-bit mantissa, like the `finit` state.)

But that doesn't affect what happens with the masked x87 stack underflow exception caused by `fcmov` when all the x87 registers were in "unwritten" state.  http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm  The tag word confirms that was the case, so `fcmov` did fault and write a NaN to `st0`, leaving the tag field for FP register #0 = 0b10 with the rest empty (tag = 0b11). And the status word confirms C1 = 0 [as `fcmov` sets](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcmovcc) on stack underflow.

Not that that matters; `FPUInstructionPointer` is set to the last non-control FPU instruction whether it faults or not; I had that wrong when commenting on the question and suggesting that a non-faulting `fcmov` might account for the null pointer.